# Dynamically add divider to last item in list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

i am progrmatically adding list view to a linear layout like this:

```
ArrayList<Answer> ans = (ArrayList<Answer>) ques.getAnswers();
    adapter = new AnswerAdapter(Test.this, ans);

    ansList = new ListView(Test.this); // my list view adding dynamically
    ansList.setAdapter(adapter);
    ansList.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    ansList.setOnItemClickListener(cellClickListener);
    ansLayout.addView(ansList);
```

Now the problem is it has the default divider after each item except the last item, i want the divider to be visible after the last item also.

I have looked into many questions in SO where they are adding views in the layout but i need to add programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add footer view in listview... so make a layout of footerview...  and bind as below

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.track_footer_view, null, false);
listview.addFooterView(footerView);
```

so you can have footerview at end of last item..

Comment: put divider image in this layout.. so you can see that layout at the end of listview

Comment: ok you mean add an image view in this layout? ...thanks will check that now, thanks a lot

Comment: @SanketKachhela sorry to disturb you again but its still not adding to the last item... please help.. this is my layout <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/img"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ans_back"/>
    

</LinearLayout>

Comment: setAdapter after this 2 line of code OR Show your new java code

Comment: actually its adding but the last item is too much space so the image is well below the item

Comment: @SanketKachhela you are great, you made my day its working fine now i am accepting the answer the answer

Answer (score 0):

**-** Add that separator as the `footer` to your `ListView`.

**Eg:**

```
View mfooter = View.inflate(MyClass.this, R.layout.imagelayout, null);
lv.addFooterView(mfooter, null, false);
```

Comment: what is this R.layout.imagelayout here and what does this layout will have.

Comment: @Goofy here `R.layout.imagelayout` is an example of a layout that will represent your **footer (ie separator)**